# No such file pyconfig.h in cpp proj

Tags: python, c++, boost, clion, boost-python

So, I'm trying to integrate some python code to c++ project. For that purpose I've created simple test project using clion. But met with a problem. Working on OS - Ubuntu 18.04.2

```
"/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:11: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory" on the line 

include boost/python.hpp
```

Seen some solutions like:

> "add export
>   CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/include/python2.7/" to
>   bashrc".

Tried that - nothing.

Here is the cmakelist

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(pythonInCPPIntegration)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
find_package(Boost 1.65.1 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(pythonInCPPIntegration main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pythonInCPPIntegration ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

C-proj looks like that, nothing more

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main() {

}
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was kinda linkage problem. Solved with some manipulations over cmakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(pythonInCPPIntegration)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
find_package(Boost 1.65.1 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
add_executable(pythonInCPPIntegration main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pythonInCPPIntegration ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```